# What is the name of this statistical filter?

Tags: statistics

I have a piece of code that takes a noisy data set and uses some sort of statistical filter to plot a trend line over the noisy data. The original author of the code no longer works at my job, so I can't ask him what the filter is. I've included a math-ified version of his code, and **I would love to know what the filter is called so I can learn more about it**. Here's a code/math snippet.

First, a bunch of variables are set. The first element of `filtered` is set to just be the average of the noisy data, just so we have a value to use in the first iteration of the loop. `filtered` will contain all the filtered points from the noisy dataset called `noisy`.

$\beta = 0.00001 \\
\sigma = 0.005 \\ 
\overline{p}_0 = 1 \\
q = 1 \\
k = \frac{\overline{p}_0}{\overline{p}_0 + 1} \\
p = k \\ 
filtered[0] = avg(noisy)$

Then, we enter a loop, and forgive me if this is a little confusing. For each element $i$ in `noisy`, do the following things:

$m_i = e^{-\beta} \\ 
\gamma = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2(1-m_i^2)}{2\beta}} \\ 
\phi = m_i \\
\overline{\eta} = \phi \cdot filtered(i) \\
\overline{p}_i = \phi \cdot p \cdot (\phi + \gamma) \cdot q \cdot \gamma \\
k = \frac{\overline{p}_i}{\overline{p}_i + 1} \\ 
filtered[i] = \overline{\eta} + k \cdot (noisy[i] - \overline\eta) \\
p = k$

**Does anyone recognize anything from this math/code sample?** The filter seems to work (I wrote a simple moving average filter and compared the two and it looks pretty good to me). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe crossvalidated / statistics .SE would be a better fit for the question.

Comment: Or SE.DSP / Signal procesing